# Do level 10840 and 11026 specialists give the full effect?

Tags: psp, disgaea

In the PSP version of Disgaea, Disgaea: Afternoon of Darkness, it is possible to get subdued specialists from Foresights and Tainted Staffs. Broker, Manager, Statistician, Armsmaster at level 10840 and alchemists on the staffs at level 11026.

The max level for a Statistician is 300 which will increase your exp gain +300%. My question is, will a level 10840 increase exp gain by +10,840%? Or is it less powerful than level 300? And why?

***Experimental Data***

I've actually recorded some real data but can't figure out the exact effect they have.

The formula for exp gain seems to be: [Exp Gain = 0.02 * Enext * EP + 6](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/589678-disgaea-hour-of-darkness/faqs/26230)

On the map first map of the Final Episode I combined the 4 monsters to create a level 570 Neuntoter with "NEXT" displaying as 1,028,004. (passed ~5 stronger monster proposals)

With this we get: Exp = 0.02 * 1028004 * 20 + 6 = 411207.6

My completely new Recruit gained 4,168,848 Exp With 8 level 10840 Statisticians leveling to level 89.

If 8 level 300 Statisticians would increase experience by +2400% or x25. Then she should have gained 10,280,175. Since this seems to be an increase of ~914% I think there's an error in my calculations!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to KlayBuddy on GameFAQs, there is still a cap:](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/935234-disgaea-afternoon-of-darkness/40061867)

> Statiscian, Brokers, and Managers are capped at 300%, whereas Armsmaster is capped at 1900%.
>
> NOTE: Even with the Foresight glitch, the cap is still the cap. It does not matter if you have 2 sets of Statiscians, a Statiscian with <Insert some big number here>, an Armsmaster with a billion power, it will still be what the cap says.

There is a variety of other information about the Foresight-related glitches in that thread - notably, don't equip a glitched one as your Jump will be reduced to -100 and you can't move.

Comment: Actually if you equip two glitched ones your jump returns to normal (and if you equip three you can't move again)

Comment: Equipping foresights increase jump values by 136. However, since the game uses signed 8bit integers you get overflow. Adding an additional one will increase your jump by 16. The deltas are 0 -> -120 -> 16 -> -108 -> etc

Comment: Aha! My calculations would have shown +300% but I forgot to take into account the +100% Geo Symbol and +50% for a boss. Which gives a near enough number! :D shame that your can't stack them though :(